# Selecting a few items in ComboBoxEdit

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

I use [ComboBoxEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfEditorsComboBoxEdittopic) ([DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com)) with [CheckedComboBoxStyle](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/clsDevExpressXpfEditorsCheckedComboBoxStyleSettingstopic.aspx) settings for filter. How I can select a few items through code?

Comment: windows forms right? how are you filling the ComboBox control with items? did you try to loop on all available items and set the Checked/Selected property?

Comment: WPF. Filling using ItemsSource

Comment: does this help? http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q330727.aspx?searchtext=set+checked+items

Comment: I hope. Tomorrow can check. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add necessary items to the [ComboBoxEdit.SelectedItems](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfEditorsLookUpEditBase_SelectedItemstopic) collection

Markup:

```
xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
...
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="cbEdit" IsTextEditable="False">
    <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
        <dxe:CheckedComboBoxStyleSettings />
    </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
</dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
```

Code behind:

```
string[] platforms = new string[] { "Win98", "Win2000", "WinNT", "WinXP", "Vista", "Win7" };
cbEdit.ItemsSource = platforms;
cbEdit.SelectedItems.Add(platforms[4]);
cbEdit.SelectedItems.Add(platforms[5]);
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation:

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsCheckedComboBoxEdittopic

To edit a set of Boolean options, add corresponding items to the RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit.Items collection. Each item is represented by a CheckedListBoxItem object, providing the following options:

```
ListBoxItem.Value - represents the item's value. Typically, this property must specify a unique string. For check items, it's also possible to specify the display text via the CheckedListBoxItem.Description property.
CheckedListBoxItem.CheckState - represents the item's check state (checked or unchecked). The indeterminate state is not supported.
CheckedListBoxItem.Enabled - specifies whether the item's state can be changed by an end-user.
```